# How can I switch off infix spacing for some symbols?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to write strings that contain asterisks, but LaTeX sees the asterisks as infix operators and surrounds them with spaces. How can I switch this off?

```
\[
 aaa*aaa*aaa
\]
```

Should look like

```
\[
aaa\!*\!aaa\!*\!aaa 
\]
```

Comment: Actually, shouldn't you want the look of `$aaa{*}aaa{*}aaa$` if the objective is to print the string as is? By default, TeX places `\medmuskip` between items of the `mathord` and `mathbin`; using `\!` removes only `\thinmuskip`, not `\medmuskip`.

Comment: Is the `*` symbol the only one that's causing trouble, or are there other symbols of type mathbin or mathrel inside the strings that need to be printed "as is"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you never need `*` as an infix binary operator, you can change its math code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\mathcode`*=\numexpr\mathcode`*-"2000\relax

\begin{document}

\[
aaa*aaa*aaa
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If it is for a one-off case,

```
\[
aaa{*}aaa{*}aaa
\]
```

would do.